# Как правильно?

Tags: стилистика

В Интернете встретил такое предложение "Придет время, когда ты решишь, что все кончено. Это и будет начал***о***"А если написать "Придет время, когда ты решишь, что все кончено - это и будет начало***(м)"***.  Хотелось бы узнать , есть ли какая нибудь стилистическая разница ? 
Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Серж, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Я -то отмечаю, но толка мало. Обратите внимание: у меня ноль принятых.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант 1. Как определить начало нового пути? Придет время, когда ты решишь, что все кончено, - это и будет начало.

Вариант 2.  Ты мечтаешь начать новую жизнь, когда в ней  наступают трудные моменты, и отмечаешь разные  события как начало нового пути, но каждый раз ошибаешься в своих расчетах.    Но придет время, когда ты решишь, что все кончено. Это и будет начало.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

В первом случае мы используем присоединительную конструкцию,  которая повторяет тему предыдущего предложения, поэтому здесь не делается длительная пауза.

Во втором случае эти темы непосредственно не соприкасаются, поэтому делается более длительная пауза, вносящая элемент неожиданности. Держите паузу!

ОТВЕТ 2

1) Это и будет началом. Творительный предикативный обозначает развернутый во времени признак; кроме того, в современном языке  он постепенно вытесняет именительный падеж во всех значениях. Поэтому данный вариант соответствует обычному нейтральному стилю.

2) Это и будет начало. Именительный предикативный  фиксирует время, четко определяя событие и тем самым придавая ему особую значимость и художественность. Этот вариант в большей соответствует тематике текста.

Comment: Вы меня не поняли. Меня интересует не пунктуационное оформление . С этим все ясно. Обратите внимание на выделенное окончание. Меня это интересует.

Comment: Спасибо, София.